# Android - Keeping arraylist updated between 2 activities using File

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to:

Save words in Main Activity and show them as a listView (+checkbox) in another Activity called ShowAll.

Problem is that:

Every time I remove an item in ShowAll => press back to go to Main activity => add a new item: Along with the added item, the old removed item appears as well.

```
// this method opens the new activity and passes the list
public void findAll(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ShowAll.class);
        fh = new FileH(); // simple File read-write class
        i.putStringArrayListExtra("data", fh.read("etitaa.txt", this));
        startActivity(i);
}

// Deleting an item within the new activity
    public void Delete(View view) {
        list.remove(currentItem);
        FileH fh = new FileH();
        fh.write(list, "etitaa.txt", this);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
```

I have no idea what would be the best way to pass the list back to the MainActivity. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: how are you launching your new activity? are you perhaps using `startActivityForResult()` call?

Comment: findAll() within the MainActivity starts the new activity called ShowAll... right? But when I return (by using back button) from ShowAll to MainActivity, I need a way to pass the ArrayList back. Currently im doing it by using File read-write each time but it doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: is it your file updated.??

Comment: Good question, I still havent found the file actually... ugh

Comment: I guess the files are hidden... sweet, didnt think this was going to be this hard. Any other way to do this than by using File?

Comment: If you need them persisted beyond the lifetime of your app (ie be able to open them after a restart), you can use the built in SqlLite for storage. If you don't care about that and only want to pass them between activities, you can try using Intents (answered below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use the file, unless that's what you want. You can easily do this using `Intent` objects and `startActivityForResult()` method.

ActivityMain:

```
public void startNextActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivitySecond.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("data", list);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<String> returnedData = data.getStringArrayListExtra("data");
        //... do what you want with the updated list...
    }
}
```

ActivitySecond:

```
ArrayList<String> updatedList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    updatedList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("data", null);
    //Use this list when removing items from it in the second activity
}

@Override
public void finish() {
    Intent result = new Intent();
    result.putStringArrayListExtra("data", updatedList);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, result); //<-- added second parameter
    super.finish();
}
```

Comment: Looks solid answer but getting the following. The list is definitely not null before finish() method runs. 

java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=null} to activity {Activity_main}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Could you post the entire stack trace? It appears that you didn't launch your second activity correctly. Also make sure that neither ActivityMain nor ActivitySecond are `singleInstance` activities

Comment: Is this the line 61: `ArrayList<String> returnedData = data.getStringArrayList();` ? If not, paste it here, please. That's where the NPE is thrown

Comment: ArrayList<String> returnedData = data.getStringArrayListExtra("data");

getStringArrayList doesnt exist it says

Comment: Yeah, that's how it's supposed to be. But I remembered what was missing, see the updated answer